# Definition of the tensor product of representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products

I'm a bit confused about the following definition:

Let $\rho_1:G \to Aut(V_1)$, $\rho: G \to Aut(V_2) $ be two representations of the same group $G$.
Then a tensor product of representations is defined as:
$$ \rho_1 \otimes\rho_2:G \to Aut(V_1 \otimes V_2)\\
    g \mapsto (\rho_1\otimes\rho_2)(g):= \rho_1(g)\otimes \rho_2(g) $$

**Question**: Isn't object $\rho_1(g)\otimes \rho_2(g)$ belongs to something like $Aut(V_1)\otimes Aut(V_2)$ (since $\rho_i(g) \in Aut(V_i)$), and not to $Aut(V_1 \otimes V_2)$?. But, honestly, then I don't understand if the tensor product of two non-abelian group is even defined.

Comment: Let $V_i = \mathbb{R}^{n_i}$ so $\rho_i \in Hom(G,GL_{n_i}(\mathbb{R}))$. You are sending an element of $Hom(G,GL_{n_1}(\mathbb{R})) \times  Hom(G,GL_{n_2}(\mathbb{R}))$ to an element of $Hom(G,GL_{n_1 n_2}(\mathbb{R}))$. The [resulting matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Intuitive_motivation_and_the_concrete_tensor_product) are $\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2(g)_{(a-1)n_2+b,(c-1)n_2+d} = \rho_1(g)_{a,c} \ \rho_2(g)_{b,d}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A:V_1\to V_1$ and $B:V_2\to V_2$ are linear transformations, then $A\otimes B$ is defined to be the unique linear transformation $V_1\otimes V_2\to V_1\otimes V_2$ that satisfies $(A\otimes B)(x\otimes y)=A(x)\otimes B(y)$.

Comment: In other words, $A\otimes B$ is the linear map determined by the bilinear map $V_1\times V_2\to V_1\otimes V_2$ that sends $(x,y)$ to $A(x)\otimes B(y)$.

Comment: Pretty clear, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Given an element
$$ x = \sum_{k} a_k v_{1, k} \otimes v_{2, k} \in V_1 \otimes V_2, $$
the action of $\rho_1 (g) \otimes \rho_2 (g)$ on $x$ is:
$$(\rho_1 (g) \otimes \rho_2 (g))(  x) = \sum_{k} a_k \rho_1 (g) ( v_{1, k}) \otimes \rho_2 (g) (v_{2, k}).$$

Thus $\rho_1 (g) \otimes \rho_2 (g)$ is a linear map from $V_1 \otimes V_2$ to $V_1 \otimes V_2$. So $\rho_1 (g) \otimes \rho_2 (g)$ is indeed in ${\rm Aut}(V_1 \otimes V_2)$.